# SQL update multiple rows in destination table with same id but different values from other table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

creditNote table

```
id      invoice_id     generated_at(timestamp)     status
10101      111          2018-02-28 14:42:39.247         generated
23982      111          2018-03-30 11:11:11.247          generated
```

paymentModeAmount table

```
id      invoice_id     paid_on(timestamp)     payment_mode
98236      111                                 creditNote
63725      111                                 creditNote
```

After execution of below query OUTPUT is

paymentModeAmount table

```
id        invoice_id     paid_on(timestamp)       payment_mode
98236        111         2018-02-28 14:42:39.247   creditNote 
63725        111         2018-02-28 14:42:39.247   creditNote
```

Here PaidOn Column has same data, but we need to get two different timestamps

Expected

```
id      invoice_id     paid_on(timestamp)       payment_mode
98236      111         2018-02-28 14:42:39.247   creditNote 
63725      111         2018-03-30 11:11:11.247   creditNote
```

paidOn timestamp's should be different as expected

PL/SQL Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatePaidOn()
RETURNS TABLE(
invoiceid BIGINT,
generatedat TIMESTAMP)
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT
generated_invoice_id as invoiceid, generated_at as generatedat
FROM
credit_note
WHERE
status='generated';
END; $$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Execute the below function

```
UPDATE payment_mode_amount pm
SET paid_on = sq.generatedat
from updatePaidOn() as sq
where pm.invoice_id = sq.invoiceid
and pm.paid_on is null
and pm.payment_mode='creditNote';
```

Update accordingly timestamps..

Comment: You must enumerate records (totally or in some group) in both tables (as I understand the `id` values you show are fake and are not equal in practice) and use additional joining by this number (and group if exists). In current state both `updatePaidOn()` records match all conditions for all records in `payment_mode_amount`, so first joined record is used for update only, which cause similar result values.

Comment: Yes, id values are just fake, but when record is matched, picking only first value of generated_at timestamp and updating in credit_note with two records with same value only

Comment: I do not see any reason to set the timestamps in the order you show. Will the desired output be correct if we will switch timestamp field values in these 2 records?

Comment: `10:34:11:11:11:12` is not a timestamp. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Timestamp is a just value (will store in generated_at column), Actually we are picking generated_at values from credit note table(invoice_id='111') which matches in payment mode amount table (invoice_id = '111'), then output should be reflected in payment mode amount table(paid_on column) (with two different values pulled from credit note table).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay, updated timestamp accordingly..

Comment: Isn't that a simple UPDATE with a join? https://rextester.com/QGTGR93729  (the function seems to be completely unnecessary)

Comment: Yes, you right but, credit_note and payment_mode_amount tables (id's are different) not 1,2 and 1,2, it may be different like 10001, 121221 and 84647, 53362 Just I kept it sample. (without matching with id column in two tables we need to get the output that were showed in rextester.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care which timestamp is used for which target row, you can match the two tables by joining them on a generated "row number" using e.g. this:

```
with cn as (
  select id, invoice_id, generated_at, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from creditnote
  where status = 'generated'
), pnr as (
  select id, invoice_id, generated_at, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from paymentmodeamount
  where payment_mode = 'creditNote'
)
select *
from pnr 
  join cn on cn.rn = pnr.rn and cn.invoice_id = pnr.invoice_id;
```

This joins the rows based on the ordering of the ID values in the tables `creditnote` and `paymentmodeamount`. If you want you can also order the `creditnote` table by `generated_at`.

Given your sample data this would return something like this (this is only to demonstrate what the above join does):

```
id    | invoice_id | generated_at | rn | id    | invoice_id | generated_at        | rn
------+------------+--------------+----+-------+------------+---------------------+---
63725 |        111 |              |  1 | 10101 |        111 | 2018-02-28 14:42:39 |  1
98236 |        111 |              |  2 | 23982 |        111 | 2018-03-30 11:11:11 |  2
```

Now the above query can be used as part of an UPDATE statement to bring the rows together.

```
with cn as (
  select id, invoice_id, generated_at, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from creditnote
  where status = 'generated'
), pnr as (
  select id, invoice_id, generated_at, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from paymentmodeamount
  where payment_mode = 'creditNote'
)
update paymentmodeamount p
   set generated_at = cn.generated_at
from pnr 
  join cn on cn.rn = pnr.rn and cn.invoice_id = pnr.invoice_id
where p.id = pnr.id
  and p.generated_at is null;
```

This assumes that `paymentmodeamount.id` is the primary key of the table.

Note that this won't be very fast for large tables.

Online example: https://rextester.com/YXAK25669

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "update"
LINE 11: update paymentmodeamount p
         ^

Comment: with cn as (
 select id, generated_invoice_id, generated_at, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
 from credit_note
 where status = 'generated'
), pnr as (
 select id, invoice_id, paid_on, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
 from payment_mode_amount
 where payment_mode = 'creditNote' 
)

update payment_mode_amount p
  set paid_on = cn.generated_at
from pnr 
 join cn on cn.rn = pnr.rn and cn.generated_invoice_id = pnr.invoice_id
where p.id = pnr.id
 and p.paid_on is null;

Comment: Thanks, but is there any alternate solution, i have more than 3 lakhs records on paymentmodeamount table.

Comment: @GaganMesala: you probably made some error when copying and pasting the code. I just checked with 9.5 and it works there as well: https://i.imgur.com/6ClAGDh.png

Comment: @GaganMesala: with such a database design, I don't see any other solution.